# python virtualenvwrapper producing an EOL error on install

Tags: windows, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I was trying to use the pip package

> virtualenvwrapper

in Windows through gitbash.  The standard virtualenvwrapper-win doesn't work in gitbash and it's useful to not have to switch between consoles so I generally install both.

Normally you simply need to open your .bashrc file in your home directory and type something akin to the following:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Envs/ 
source Path/To/Python/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

In this case, however, this produced an error complaining that it reached EOL (end of line) while scanning the string literal.  It showed the offending line and it was trying to combine the gitbash $HOME variable (with forward slashes) with the windows environment variable (with the backslashes).

How can I fix it so that it's not combining the environment variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution is to manually force the script to find the right path by opening virtualenvwrapper.sh and editing line 126:

```
"$VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON" -c "import os,sys; sys.stdout.write('/path/to/your/envs/folder')"
```

The underlying cause, however, occurs if you try to set an environment variable in windows for WORKON_HOME.  If you simply want to share the Envs folder in your home directory, delete the WORKON_HOME environment variable you created in windows and the issue should go away.

If you want it in a completely different place, then use the absolute path (no environment variables such as %USERPROFILE%) in the windows environment variable and it should work.